# The reputation graph doesn't work properly when the webpage is zoomed in

Tags: bug, reputation-graph

Safari 10.1.1 (12603.2.4), macOS Sierra 10.12.5

By reputation graph I mean this:

[image]

When I zoom in to the maximum on the webpage (making a "zoom in" gesture on my trackpad), the graph does not work properly anymore.

Usually when you hover the pointer over the graph, a tooltip will show up that shows you the y-axis value for the x value that the pointer is standing on:

[image]

When I zoom in though, the tooltip shows the wrong value or does not show at all.

I think this is a bug. Can it be fixed?

Comment: Can't reproduce this on android with chrome.

Comment: Stack Overflow does not generally support zoomed views of their web pages. If it works for you at 100% zoom, then I assume this is [[meta-tag:status-bydesign]]

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this on Safari 12.1 (13607.1.40.1.5) / macOS High Sierra 10.13.6. Also no repro on Chrome 73.0.3683.86. Unless someone can reproduce this on a recent Safari version, I'm inclined to assume that this was a Safari bug that has been fixed.