# Stack Overflow Sidebar is a leftist

Tags: bug, design, sidebar

I just noticed that the sidebar on both Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow has no background, which under normal circumstances may not be a problem, but to guys with a large monitor and poor eyesight who (occasionally) use zoom, like me, it becomes one as soon as we decide to scroll horizontally.

I don't believe it's designed that way for some shady purpose, is it?

**Data:**

The issue seems to be that unlike other browsers where it's scrolled past normally, in Edge, the sidebar stays fixed to the left. I tested it in:

- Microsoft Edge 41.16299.15.0 (**occurs**)
- Google Chrome 68.0.3440.84 (**doesn't occur**)
- Mozilla Firefox 61.0.1 (**doesn't occur**)
- Opera 54.0.2952.64 (**doesn't occur**)

**Screencast** → [here](https://youtu.be/Hx43LGWmMTE)

**Screenshot:**

[image: View on Imgur]

**Update:**

Since I had some free time today, I decided to give a look at what is causing this particular behaviour of the sidebar in Microsoft Edge. After playing a bit with the code in the console, I figured out that the problem resides in the element `div.left-sidebar--sticky-container.js-sticky-leftnav`.

The problem seems to be the fact that one extra class is added to that element in Microsoft Edge. The `class` attribute of the element is:

- Microsoft Edge: `left-sidebar--sticky-container js-sticky-leftnav left-sidebar__fake-sticky`
- Other browsers: `left-sidebar--sticky-container js-sticky-leftnav`

By removing the `left-sidebar__fake-sticky` class being used in Microsoft Edge but in no other browser, the problem seems to subside, without any apparent side-effects.

Comment: I can't make it scroll. It looks like you're using Firefox but I also tried to repro in Chrome, what is your screensize and how much do you zoom to get the horizontal scrollbar? You are sure you don't have a userstyle that is interfering?

Comment: No, @rene I don't have any such setting set. Also, the browser I'm using is clearly Microsoft Edge 

Comment: As I clearly misjudged that, add the current browser and version you're running in your question and let us know if you can repro with any other browser.

Comment: Can't repro in Edge either but I don't have a very large display at hand now.

Comment: Sure @rene. I also forgot to mention that I only encounter that issue in the user page.

Comment: Yeah, I tried both your profile page and mine, in case it was something related to content only found on your profile page.

Comment: The sidebar seems to be that specific brand of person that feels called upon to meddle in other people's business and talk over what they have to say. An outrage!

Comment: Any plugin interfering? I see at least uBlock is installed. Try to disable all plugins; does this issue still happen without plugins?

Comment: @Caramiriel I've already tried disabling all my extensions, but the issue doesn't seem related.

Comment: @AngelPolitis - are you aware you can just hide the left navigation altogether?  The option is on [**this page in the 'Navigation' section**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/).

Comment: unable to reproduce in edge or any other browser, using combined two monitors. maybe you need to make a video about how you get it to happen?

Comment: @ashleedawg yes I'm aware. I just mentioned it, so that if it's a bug, the people responsible for the site's maintenance are put to notice of it.

Comment: @eis I have uploaded a video reproducing the issue [here](https://youtu.be/Hx43LGWmMTE).

Comment: @AngelPolitis - absolutely - just wanted to make sure you knew.  :-)   (I'm [not a fan](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311215/370758) of the sidebar in general.)

Comment: @ashleedawg me neither 

Comment: I did the same thing as in the video, but still couldn't repro. Interestingly, the scrollbar only appears when you're in someone's profile page; it doesn't show when looking at questions.

Comment: I'm using Edge 42.17134.1.0, so perhaps upgrade?

Comment: What is your sidebar preferences? Autohide, hide, or keep?

Comment: @HongOoi actually I have updated Edge now, but still updating is more of a shortcut than actually a solution to the problem. Aren't you curious to find out what's causing it?

Comment: @Braiam I have the `Hide left navigation` checkbox unchecked.

Comment: "Also, the browser I'm using is clearly Microsoft Edge" <-- Welp, there's your problem

Comment: @CharlesSrstka hahaha, that's just bad! For the record, I was setting up a brand new PC and I hadn't downloaded Chrome and Firefox yet 

Comment: I can repro in Edge 40.15063.674.0

Comment: Unable to reproduce in Safari 11.1

Comment: I think this is [tag:status-bydesign]. See [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354958/the-reputation-graph-doesnt-work-properly-when-the-webpage-is-zoomed-in#comment503600_354958) Stack Overflow apparently doesn't "support zoomed views of their web page".

Comment: @Sweeper That's terrible.  "We don't support zoom" is loosely equivalent to "we don't care about people with limited vision" who may need to zoom extensively to get text large enough to comfortably read.

Comment: @DanNeely I know right? But a moderator said that, do it’s probably true?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I edited your comment, as it had two separate flags on it. I'm so tired of this comment debacle and flagging insanity. As  mod I cannot win. Dammed if I do, dammed if I don't, dammed if I try a compromise. It will end up on meta and I will be accused of all sorts of things. I'm tired of it. please understand why I changed the one word.

Comment: @Yvette as I understand you can skip flags and leave controversial matters to other mods. Censorship sounds like a controversial matter.

Comment: @AndrasDeak ironically, we're talking about that very issue right now in the mod chat room. Leave the flags for other mods. And if they sit there, they sit there.

Comment: @Yvette I've never been a huge fan of this flag frenzy so it's unsurprising that I'm OK with comment flags sitting around rather than being mishandled ;) Unless the flags were rude/abusive...I guess that's harder to push off.

Comment: @AndrasDeak it's hard. Because we either ignore the flags. this leave a lot of flags that will be overlooked. Or we decline. and then we get hit with a post. "why was my flag declined?" or we delete the comment and get a post "why was my comment deleted?"

Comment: @Yvette yeah, there's a clear conflict of interest between flaggers and flaggees. And we've learned that the line is so unclear that it barely exists. Fortunately we have our dear mods to decide about each ;) My remark was mainly that if you feel between a rock and a hard place, deferring to others could be a way out for you personally (knowing how a lot of users react to whatever you do on meta).

Comment: @AndrasDeak yes, I understood and appreciate your advice. Especially the timing :) Need to lock down that OCD of wanting to clear the flag queue. Curse those numbered notifications. It's like unread emails of FB notifications.

Comment: @YvetteColomb thanks for letting me know! I understand and I hope my wording in the mod flag didn't suggest anything but inquiry and mild disappointment over a joke (read, nothing terribly important) that is no longer that funny in the new form. The debacle isn't the mods' making and they shouldn't have to take the heat for it. :(

Comment: @Pekka웃  yeh I get that. I'm learning to skip and allow other mods to handle or choose to not handle flags. Much of this comes from flags that sit around and other wise mods leave and I then decide to handle them. That's my mistake. You know I have no issues with you and welcome your sanity every time I see you :)

Comment: oh, also of interest about [editing comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237978/a-guide-to-moderating-comments/238095#238095). Now I've seen and bookmarked [A guide to moderating comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237978/a-guide-to-moderating-comments), hopefully that will help.